# What's the recommended ElasticSearch deployment on Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, apache-zookeeper

Bearing in mind that the ElasticSearch-Zookeeper plugin doesn't support v0.90 release.
With unicast, what's your strategy on updating your list of IPs? I.e. when upgrading/scaling-up/down.

What client-side connectivity (from web/worker role) to the cluster? Do you:

a) implement your own round-robin/failover implementation across all nodes in the cluster

b) spin up a local (non-data/non-master) elasticsearch process on the client machine that joins the unicast cluster. The application will only connect to localhost

Where do you store your data? Azure blob gateway?

Can you share your detailed story on your ElasticSearch experience on azure, and any particular points/issues to watch out for?

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a note about this. We are on the way on releasing Azure plugin for Elasticsearch. It will help to allow automatic discovery of your Elasticsearch nodes. I think that we will have something public in the next weeks.

Also, I recommend to use local storage. Azure blob will be used in the future to allow snapshots (and restore) feature when Elasticsearch 1.0 will be out.

Hope this helps

Update: Plugin is now available here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-azure

Comment: Still working on it with azure team. I hope that we will be able to make it public in september.

Comment: Is there anyway I can be notified when this comes about? I have a direct need for this today.

Comment: Sorry. It's not ready. I don't think it will be out before end of october. Still working on it but hard to have a proper Azure Java SDK fully working for VM management.

Comment: Update on this. We have a pre-alpha non public version. Anyone would like to test it and give feedback? If so, please send me a private message.

Comment: @dadoonet Could not find how to send a PM on SO! :) Anyway, would be very interested in the Azure plugin if it's still relevant, thanks.

Comment: Hi Thomas! Drop me an email at david (at) pilato.fr. That said, I think we will open the plugin for the community at the very beginning of 2014! :-)

Comment: Updated my answer as we released the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

It's in no way certified by ElasticSearch, but I wrote a blog post about my experience running ES on Azure: http://thomasardal.com/running-elasticsearch-in-a-cluster-on-azure/